# Can't assign width to FlatList item

Tags: react-native, styled-components, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

I'm having a problem assigning the width to cards contained within a FlatList. I tried to assign 50% width to the FlatList columns using `columnWrapperStyle={{ width: "50%" }}`, but it doesn't work.

I'm using a FlatList to display a list of Cards in two columns

```
   const DATA: Item[] = [
    {
      id: "1",
      title: "First Item",
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      title: "Second Item",
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      title: "Third Item",
    },
    {
      id: "4",
      title: "Fourth Item",
    },
  ];
  const renderItem = ({ item }: { item: Item }) => (
    <FavCard title="Mojito" description="Description" />
  );
  return (
    <FavouriteCocktailsContainer>
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        horizontal={false}
        numColumns={2}
        columnWrapperStyle={{ width: "50%" }}
      />
    </FavouriteCocktailsContainer>
```

The style of the item *FavCard* is the following:

```
export const CardContainer = styled.TouchableOpacity`
  width: 100%;
  height: 208px;
  border-radius: 16px;
`;
```

and *FavouriteCocktailsContainer*:

```
export const FavouriteCocktailsContainer = styled.View`
  width: 100%;
`;
```

This is what I get:

[image]

I want the cards to be 50% width of the *FavouriteCocktailsContainer*, do you know how I can fix this?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please try to remove `columnWrapperStyle` props or set the `width` to 100% because this is style for every column. You have 2 columns so the width must be 50% compared to the outter container width which is 100% of the screen width. So if you set `width: "50%"`, each column will be 25$ of the screen width.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I already tried removing the prop or setting it to 100%, but it doesn't work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

1. Remove `columnWrapperStyle` props.
2. set width to the `renderItem`

Get width from `Dimensions`(declare this at the top)

```
const { width }=Dimensions.get("window")
```

and use it in `renderItem` method

```
const renderItem = ({ item }: { item: Item }) => (
    <View style={{width: width/2}}><FavCard title="Mojito" description="Description" /></View>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

just change it

```
 columnWrapperStyle={{ width: "50%" }}
```

to

```
 columnWrapperStyle={{ justify-content: "space-between" }}
```

and define width of your item with exact value or flex:1. but width not in %percentage.

example

```
export const CardContainer = styled.TouchableOpacity`
  width: 100%; // No
  width: your width of item exp 200// YES
  flex: 1 // Yes
  height: 208px;
  border-radius: 16px;
`;
```